# jboss Resteasy for java 5

Tags: resteasy

Is there a resteasy version that runs on jdk 5 enviroment? I tried to compile my code in java 5 but it didnot work saying version problem. Is there a solution here?

> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an
>   internal error () that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error
>   instantiating servlet class
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   Bad version number in .class file
>   (unable to load class
>   javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1964)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:933)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1405)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
>     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native
>   Method)
>     java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2357)
>     java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2671)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:321)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root
>   cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/5.5.31 logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for updating.  This is the same error that you have asked about in your other question here [How to use java 6 features in a java 5 environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537673/how-to-use-java-6-features-in-a-java-5-environment), isn't it?

Basically the answers given to that question are correct and describe the solution your problem.

Resteasy specifics:  The latest Resteasy distribution (2.1.0.GA) does seem to be compiled for JRE 6, but 2.0.1.GA is OK with JRE 5 (or the source is provided if you want to compile it yourself).  Ideally, upgrade the version of java used on the server.  Later versions have performance improvements if nothing else.

Finally, make sure you are not confusing the version of tomcat (5 or 6) with the version of Java (also, coincidentally 5 or 6).

Comment: the codes are compiling fine. But when deploying it shows error. Please see the error above. The question has been updated. also, I am compiling using apache tomcat 6 and 5.5, both show same error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No i am not confusing with tomcat versions; its jdk. Also can you give me the link for resteast 2.1.0 or 2.0.1 GA sources so that i can compile it with jdk 5?

Comment: Resteasy download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/resteasy/files/Resteasy%20JAX-RS/  [source: google]

Comment: No 2.0.1 also not supported woth JRE 5